# SQL Server Linked Server Permissions

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

On a SQL Server 7 server, I have a linked server to a Sybase database server running this command:

```
select * from openquery(SYBASE_SERVER, 'select * from DBA.TESTTABLE')
```

works fine if I'm logged in as an SA.

If I try to run it while logged in as non-SA, it fails with the error:

> Server: Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Could not create an
>   instance of OLE DB provider 'ASAProv.90'.

What permissions do I need to grant the user to let it work as a NON-sa account?

Comment: What is the service account for the SQL Server service? What is the non-sa user you are trying to use - windows auth or SQL auth? Also, seriously - SQL Server 7.0?

Comment: The service account for MSSQLServer is just a generic domain account we user for our SQL servers.  The non-SA user (testuser) is using SQL auth.  If I just make testuser a SA, it works, so I know it's just a permission issue.

Comment: SQL Server 7.0's linked servers were a bit different and I don't have access to SQL 7.0 right at the moment, but can you let us know what settings are selected under the security tab of the linked server settings? Also, what provider options are selected for the provider for the ASA/Sybase provider in the providers list?

Comment: GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.XP_PROP_OLEDB_PROVIDER TO account_name

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, try this. I *think* this is how I fixed it some time ago...

```
exec sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1; reconfigure;
exec sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1; reconfigure;
go
```

Edit, attempt 2:

Check this. I've seen this at a previous company (I wasn't sysadmin there) and can't remember what teh DBAs had to do for us to get our linked server to work (also Sybase)

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dataaccesstechnologies/permissions-needed-to-set-up-linked-server-with-out-of-process-provider)

Comment: Thanks, but "Show Advanced Options" was already set to 1 and "Ad Hoc Distributed Queries" doesn't exist in SQL 7.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  Tried Attempt #2, but still no luck.  It's got to be SQL Server permissions issue.  The query works if my user (a sql authenticated user) is a member of the System Administrators role.  It fails if the user is not.